# java.io.IOException:Cannot run program "sh" (in directory"c:\cygwin\bin\test"):CreateProcess error=2.The system cannot find file specified

Tags: java, cygwin, cygpath

I am running shell scripts with the help of java and cygwin. When i am running my code in windows xp it works fine. Now i am trying to run same code on windows 7 i am getting above error.

```
(java.io.IOException)java.io.IOException:
Cannot run program "sh" (in directory"c:\cygwin\bin\test"):
CreateProcess error=2.The system cannot find file specified
```

Why this error occurred.I have set my path for cygwin `(PATH=.;c:\cygwin\bin)` How to avoid this.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder ();
pb.directory(new File("C:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test\\"));
File shellfile = new File("app.sh");//File name with extension
System.out.println(shellfile.getCanonicalPath());
```

But it is giving the output as `E:\NIRAJ\example\app.sh` which is in my java  program. even i am setting up pb.directory to the path.

if i check `System.out.print(pb.directory());` it gives me output `C:\cygwin\bin\Test`

Comment: try to run i with admin privileges. Start command line with admin privileges then run the java from command line (or start your IDE with the rights)

Comment: So test is your file or directory ?

Comment: @programmer_1: Test is my directory.inside this directory app.sh is the shell script file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to get the path of specified file first to ensure it:

I am not much sure but this may lead you one step ahead :

```
File file = new File("app.sh");//File name with extension
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

This should print : `c:\cygwin\bin\test`
Also use separator like this instead : `c:\\cygwin\\bin\\test`

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

```
String myCommand = "c:\\cygwin\\bin\\test\\cygbin";
String myArg = PATH_TO_shellscript+"app.sh";
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(myCommand, myArg).start();
```

Comment: So how it will run since your app.sh is in example directory and you are expecting in it Test ? also you should run the command with cygbin.exe like this : `cygbin.exe PATH/app.sh` assuming cygbin is your executable.

Comment: i am coping all the required files to the test folder. then setting pb.directory(new File("C:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test\\")); then executing the command and it is working fine with windows xp.

Comment: CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.9(0.237/5/3)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8108/discussion-between-niraj-deshmukh-and-programmer-1)

Answer (score 1):

In PATH variable, you need to put cygwin's bin directory **before** any other Windows' paths.

Do this:

```
PATH=c:\cygwin\bin:RestWindowsPaths
```

Not that:

```
PATH=RestWindowsPathVariables:c:\cygwin\bin
```